# Loading tensorflow library into C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have a trained model from Keras in python  which i want to make prediction for in C++ using tensorflow 1.2. I cant seem to get the tensorflow library into my c++ program. Anyone who can take me through the steps of doing this?
ii) Do I need to use bazel if so what are the steps in using bazel?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully built a tensorflow-gpu dynamic library via CMake and Visual Studio. And now able to predict with inception_V3 and RCNN-trained model.

I've used Visual Studio 2015, CUDA 9.0, cudNN 7.0, Python 3.5.

Here is a brief look through my steps:

1. `git clone -b r1.7 --single-branch https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git`
2. Use CMake GUI and select tensorflow options, enable "shared library" and enable-gpu-support.
3. Build `tensorflow.dll` and `tensorflow.lib` with Visual Studio using the Release mode.

There will be some errors, but easy to fix. Leave a comment if you hope to know more details, glad to help.